# Point to Raster Arcmap - incorrect pixelvalues?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, import, rasterization

I am having a problem using the arcmap point to raster tool. I have x/y coordinates for a set of data, and 1464 (2 months worth of hourly data) separate files to convert from an excel with X/Y/value to a matrix for use in another program. I already have a small python-script in order to automate the point to raster and then a raster to ascii, but in my first round of testing, the values i get out of this are really weird.

I have 6 separate excel files with x/y/value1/value2/value3... etc., which i have loaded into arcmap using the Add Data -> Add xy Data tool. However, when i convert this point data based on a value-field, it gives me a range of 0:401, whereas the actual maximum value in excel is 5.05. How can these values be so different?

Comment: did you convert your added points into a feature class before you ran the tool? which kind of `cell assignment type` did you choose for the `point to raster` conversion?

Comment: Yes, I imported them into a gdb as a feature class, and I used the mean cell assignment type. Also, I used a cellsize of 0.015, which is fairly close to the resolution of the original dataset (1x1km)

Comment: Looking at the data in arcmap, i see that the valuefields are still recognised as datatype text as opposed to double. Could this be the cause?

Comment: without being able to look at your data it's hard to keep up the guessing... if the data is not recognised as a number, you might be using the wrong decimal delimiter? also i didn't understand how a resolution of 1x1km should result in a cellsize of 0.015... maybe it would help if you added a snippet of your input data?

Comment: The data is in WGS84, and looking at gaps of nodata falling into the raster after conversion, the 0.015 cellsize was the highest resolution i could get without those gaps.

My data is formatted as follows:

X (latitude)         Y(Longitude) Precip1  Precip2  Precip3 Precip4 etc.

6,454576944 53,54746861 0,02 0,02 0 0,02

6,469072778 53,54649083 0,02 0,029999999 0 0,039999999

6,483567778 53,54551083 0,02 0,039999999 0 0,02

6,498061944 53,54452861 0,01 0,039999999 0 0,02

Comment: i don't seem to fully understand your problem, sorry. are you sure that using the comma as a decimal delimiter works? the default in ArcGIS is a point.

Comment: I just tried switching the decimal pointer, and it does not seem to have any effect on the result of the point-to-raster in arcmap. In summary for my problem: I read the xy-data in from excel using the add xy-data tool. Here, all values seem to check out. However, when i use point-to-raster, the values suddenly become way higher, Where the point data is 0 at a specific gridcell, the raster gives a value of 1, and where there is a higher value, it becomes a lot higher. So the problem really lies within point-to-raster, as the identify tool gives me the correct values for the point-data

Comment: I just recreated a (very) simplified version of your problem and my raster looks fine. which value field did you chose for your `point to raster` creation? you will have to repeat the process for all precipitation columns seperately.

Comment: I usually pick precip1. I'm thinking it might be a result of the size of the dataset (123201 data points each hour). But i do pick a single precipitation column each time.

Comment: ok. i'm afraid i cannot help anymore. hope someone else has an idea. i find it hard to recreate the problem without access to your data. good luck!

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions though. I really appreciate it

Comment: you're welcome. when you find the solution / the cause for your problem, make sure to answer your own question. and please link me in it - i'd like to know what it was

Comment: @dru87 I redid all the dataprocessing and found the problem. turns out I accidentally didn't select all precipitation data when assigning cellproperties. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I just managed to fix the problem. It turns out I didn't correctly assign the cell-properties of the precipitation data as a number in excel.